# image nesting issue in tiny mce

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I have a drag drop interface from which user can add elements to page. For example, I want to nest an image inside a paragraph. To make the text elements editable and apply styles to it, I'm using a tine mce instance. I can load contents of text element (paragraph) in the mce successfully, along with its id, class and styles until, it has a nested image inside it. Once the paragraph has a nested image, on loading the content into editor, the whole content is moved out of the original p tag (the one with id and class). I tried to write clean up processes. I found the process added on onInit of mce, worked successfully in FF, but in IE, it failed completely.
Kindly advice me, whatever I'm trying to do is feasible or not ? What can be the different ways to accomplish this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I got it :).
div is not a valid child element for p. I removed the wrapper div around the image and it was fixed.